# calcular la ubicación mas corta entre dos puntos gps en sql

Tags: mysql, gps

estoy intentando sacar la distancia mas cercana entre dos puntos (latitud y longitud) pero al intentar filtrarla en mysql me sale cualquiera (a veces la mas cercana y otras otra dependiendo de la ubicación que le dé)

Las ubicaciones de latitud y longitud están expresadas en números  enteros.
**ubicacion actual:** Latitud: 31248099
                  Longitud: 64108629

```
select locgps_codigo, locgps_id, locgps_localidad_id, localidad_nombre, locgps_latitud, locgps_longitud, locgps_tipo, locgps_nombre,
        locgps_latitud - 31248099 diflat, locgps_longitud - 64108629 diflog
        from localidad_gps 
        left join localidad on locgps_localidad_id = localidad_id where locgps_tipo = 4
        and locgps_nombre <>'' and locgps_longitud > locgps_latitud
```

Y estos son los resultados que me trae.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el problema?? no te entiendo. Cada vez, lógicamente, calcula una distancia diferente no???

Comment: claro, solo que ahi estoy forzando una ubicacion para hacer pruebas en la base de datos **** ubicacion actual: Latitud: 31248099 Longitud: 64108629 ***

Comment: la distancia entre dos puntos se calcula habitualmente con la fórmula haversine o semiverseno, hay motores de base de datos que incluyen un tipo de dato geografico y facilitan la tarea, fijate este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/q/39338167/1423096

Comment: En esa consulta al filtrar los registros comparas latitud con longitud, que son 2 valores no comparables, no hay nada de cercania ni distancia

Comment: Como dice @aloMalbarez la distancia se calcula con una fórmula. Yo mismo lo hago así en mysql en mi BD.  La pregunta es "Cuál es el problema real" ??? 

Está claro que no estás calculando bien la distancia. Nunca será la resta de las distancias ni nada parecido. Se trata de una operación que tiene en cuenta más cosas

Comment: claro la formula la vi, pero el problema es que se gurdan en numeros enteros en la base de datos de la empresa y no se como aplicarla a la que me pasaron ustades. La verdad hace poco tengo acceso a la BD de esta empresa y ando como perdido

Comment: tendrías que convertir los enteros a decimales, el problema es que pueden haber redondeos en el original que den calculos erroneos . por ejemplo 31248099 para indicar 31.248099 es fácil pero 3124809 puede indicar tanto 3.124809 como 31.248090

Comment: este error de redondeo no seria problema si el sistema es local de argentina (los max y min estan entre 20 y 55) pero es para destacar la inconveniencia de almacenar los numeros enteros sin un racional de como volverlos a su valor con decimales

Comment: Hola Alo, la verdad que como comente antes soy nuevo en este empleo y voy descubriendo cosas. No sabia, ni se me había ocurrido que podía dar una falla asi en el redondeo aunque estas cosas ya estan asi. El sistema es 100% para Argentina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez no sea la respuesta mas ágil pero para este caso fue la respuesta correcta. Desde ya agradezco a todos por la ayuda!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO MYSQL**

```
    SELECT locgps_codigo, locgps_id, locgps_localidad_id, localidad_nombre, 
    locgps_latitud, locgps_longitud, locgps_tipo, locgps_nombre,            
    abs(locgps_latitud - 30260246) + abs(locgps_longitud - 64210136) diflog
    FROM localidad_gps 
    left join localidad on locgps_localidad_id = localidad_id where locgps_tipo = 4
   and locgps_nombre <>"" and locgps_longitud > locgps_latitud
   ORDER BY diflog
```